# Grails 3 restricting columns in index view

Tags: grails, controller, view

I've returned to Grails after a number of years, and find the productivity better than ever, but hit a bit of a roadblock in the Fields plugin and "respond" method. I created a domain class with a hasMany but do not wish the index view to be cluttered with the links to those children. I could eliminate that column by placing the _table.gsp template and modifying it, but then that applies globally which I don't want.

My next attempt was to invoke "list" on the domain object within the controller and "collect" only the columns I want.  When I pass this result to "respond", the view is empty, but has no errors.

Digging a bit further I find that "respond" expects a PagedResultList which I gather is a thin wrapper around a List.  But my step above returns an ArrayList.  I can't see how to construct a PagedResultList and passing the ArrayList to "respond" quietly does nothing.

I finally got the desired appearance by kind of going backwards, using "render" and an older-style hand-built view, but that seems to defeat the purpose of the simple elegance of "respond" and the Fields plugin.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy [generating the views](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/generate-views.html) for your domain you can modify index.gsp and specify the properties like:

```
<f:table collection="${authorList}" properties="['name', 'city', 'dob']" />
```

You could also use 'except' to specify fields to skip, [docs here](https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/latest/ref/Tags/table.html)

Comment: Thank you so much Mike, I thought I'd been there before on properties and excludes, but I think I was applying to the respond method instead of to the f:table tag, that works perfectly and is in keeping with Grails philosophy etc.